# Power series of $\mathrm{Log}(-\mathrm i z)$.

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

I want to solve this problem:

> Let $z_0\in \mathbb C$ such that $\mathrm{Re}\,z_0<0$, $\mathrm{Im}\,z_0<0$.
>   Find the power series of $f(z)=\mathrm{Log}(-\mathrm i z)$ in terms of $z-z_0$ and find its radius of convergence.

I know the power series of $\mathrm{Log}(1+z)$, but I don't know how to use it here. Also, I don't know how to use the fact that $z_0$ is in the third quadrant.

Comment: where (a branch of) $\log(z)$ is holomorphic/analytic, its derivative is $1/z$, so it reduces to finding the power series of $1/(-iz)$ around $z = z_0$, and then integrating it (and finding the radius of convergence)

Comment: Try putting $\omega=z-z_0$